# sum positive and negative values separately

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
NAME    MONEY
Jane    100  
Chris  -100  
Jane     50  
Ann     -10  
Jane    -25  
Ann      17
```

And i want to write a query to sum data, in one column should be only positive amount od money in another column only negative. Output should look like this:

```
NAME    SUM_POSITIVE    SUM_NEGATIVE
Jane    150             -25
Chris   0               -100
Ann     17              -10
```

query:

```
select name, sum(money) from TABLE where money>0 group by name
union 
select name, sum(money) from TABLE where money<0 group by name;
```

shows nearly what i want, but result has duplicate names and two columns instead of three:

```
NAME    SUM
Ann     -10
Ann      17
Jane    -25
Jane    150
Chris  -100
```

Please help me rewrite my query to correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use case when

```
 select name, sum(case when money>0 then money end) SUM_POSITIVE
,sum(case when money<0 then money end) SUM_NEGATIVE
from TABLE  group by name
```

You are getting duplicate name becase union operator merge only those  rows where all column values are same, as Ann contain -10 and 17 which is distinct so its make duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You can do *conditional* aggregation instead :

```
select name, 
       sum(case when money > 0 then money end) as SUM_POSITIVE,
       sum(case when money < 0 then money end) as SUM_NEGATIVE 
from TABLE
group by name;
```